# NoReverseMatch exception when creating integration test for REST API with Python Django

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework

I've created a REST API accepting a POST request in Django. The request itself works great when calling from a React front end, there should be nothing wrong with the API itself.

I want to create integration test for the API.

I've written the below test, which is basically copy/paste from the [Django Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/) adapted to my API:

```
from django.urls import reverse, path
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

    class SendLoginEmailTest(APITestCase):

        def test_post_withValidData_loginEmailIsSent(self):
            url = reverse('api_private:send_login_email')
            data = {'email': 'validemail@email.com', 'token': '4d4ca980-cb0c-425d-8d2c-7e38cb33f38e'}
            response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I run the test using the command:

```
python3 manage.py test
```

The test fails with the following exception:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'send_login_email' not found. 'send_login_email' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

== Update ==

Content of urls.py.

```
from django.urls import path
from server.api_private.views import SendLoginEmail, ValidateEmail, IsEmailValidated, ProjectSave

app_name = "api_private"

urlpatterns = [
    path('send_login_email/', SendLoginEmail.as_view()),
    path('validate_email/', ValidateEmail.as_view()),
    path('is_email_validated/', IsEmailValidated.as_view()),
    path('project_save/', ProjectSave.as_view())
]
```

Comment: Please put your url from urls.py file here.

Comment: I've updated the question with urls.py :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't add names to your urls. `reverse` functions is looking for names. Add names to all URLs that you are going to use with `reverse` function.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('send_login_email/', SendLoginEmail.as_view(), name='send_logic_email'),
    ...,
]
```

Comment: Fantastic! That solved the issue!

I also needed to add app_name in front of the API endpoint URL, like this:

url = reverse('api_private:send_login_email')

(I've updated my original post so any readers with the same issue will see this immediately).

Thank you so much!!!